# Store notification details in MySql DB (using FCM push notifications)

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, promise, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm writing a server in Node.js and express.
I'm sending to my app users push notifications via firebase notifications, and after I send it to the user, I want to **store my notification details in MySql DB**.

I have a problem in storing the notification details, it doesn't work (rows is undefined and no data is added to the DB table).

This is my relevant code:

```
 const message_notification = {
    notification: {
        title: "notification_title",
        body: "notification_body"
    }
};

const notification_options = {
    priority: "high",
    timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24
};


admin.messaging().sendToDevice(device_token, message_notification, notification_options)
    .then( response => {      
       
        //doesn't work
        mySqlConnection.query(`insert into notifications (notification_id, body, title) values
        (?,?,?)`, [response.multicastId, message_notification.notification.body, message_notification.notification.title], (err,rows)=>
        {
            try
            {
                console.log(rows);
            }

            catch(err)
            {
                console.log(err)
            }
        });
        })
```

Comment: try adding a catch and see if you get a hint on what may be wrong

Comment: thank you, I added a catch and it's not helping (in debugging not enter to this scope of code)